# Resource (GPU) locking across docker swarm stacks

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, locking, docker-swarm

I've got multiple instances of the same stack running on a (currently single-node) swarm.  They're logically totally separate and therefore should remain different stacks.

The only thing they share is the GPU.
Sometimes, but not all the time, one of the pods in the stacks requires the GPU.
If multiple pods access the GPU at the same time, they usually get OOM exceptions, which isn't terrible, but also not desired.

**What's a good, preferably simple way of locking access to the GPU across stacks?**

Things I've considered so far:

### Lock file:

Share a volume across stacks and pods, write a lock file whenever a pod uses the GPU.

**Pros:**

- simple,
- will be easy to adapt for multiple GPUs/other resources,
- easy to implement a lease/timeout mechanism.

**Cons:**

- won't work for multi-node swarms which I may scale to in future.

### Database

Maintain another database service (Redis?) and make it available across pods.

**Pros:**

- will be easy to adapt for multiple GPUs/other resources,
- easy to implement a lease/timeout mechanism.
- works across swarm nodes.

**Con:**

- another technology/dependency in the application
- another service to maintain
- greater networking complexity in swarm.

### Don't lock, just check GPU memory

That will work, but since two services may start using the GPU at the same time, they may check memory at the same time, determine that the GPU is free, and crash when they start using the GPU simultaneously.
That's not the end of the world, but it's also not great.

Comment: Why won't the lock file work on a multi node swarm? Each container will be locking a file on a local volume on the current node, to access GPU resources on the current node. It seems perfect.

Comment: @ChrisBecke : Actually, you're right!  I'd been thinking ahead too far to locking resources that might not be local, but that's really not a problem I'm having right now.